# Is it possible to empty a string using functions in python?

Tags: python, string, function

Is it possible to empty a string using functions in python?

For example:

```
otherText="hello"

def foo(text):
    text=""

foo(otherText)
print(otherText)
```

prints

> hello

instead of an empty string. Is there a way to empty the string without assigning it a return value or using global variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible. There are 2 reasons for that

1. Python strings are immutable
2. Python implements a so called ["call by sharing" evaluation strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing):

   > The semantics of call by sharing differ from call by reference in that assignments to function arguments within the function aren't visible to the caller

Answer (score 2):

As noted by zerkms, it is strictly not possible, python does not pass argument by reference.

There are a few tricks that can be used as workarounds, such as passing a list or object, containing your string.

```
otherText=["hello"]

def foo(text):
    text[0]="Goodbye string"

foo(otherText)
print(otherText) //Goodbye string
```